# How can I read and edit an XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can I open and edit an existing XML file? I would like to modify some values like:

```
<address>myaddr</address>
```

For example, I would like to put loreal instead if myaddr. I am working in C#. I would appreciate if you can show me some code.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var address = doc.Root.Element("address");
if (address != null)
{
    address.Value = "new value";
}
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Comment: Thx a lot!! If the path to the xml file is dynamical ..how can I do this in program?

Comment: @hello, what does *dynamical* mean? Can't you use a variable?

Comment: I don't want to give the root c:\desktop\xml.

Comment: One more question. If I have: <path> <address> myaddr </address></path> how shoulr I write?

Comment: @hello, well then use a relative path, assuming the file will be located at the same folder as the executable. Abd if you have this XML you could use `doc.Root.Element("address")` as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thx. And what about <path><address> myaddr</address></path>?

Comment: @hello, `doc.Root.Element("address")`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have the following XML file:

```
<root>
    <address>myaddr</address>
</root>
```

And you want to do the replacement. There are many options. Some are explicitly modifying XML, others are translating your XML to classes, modifying and translating back to XML (serialization). Here is one of the ways do do it:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
doc.Root.Element("address").Value = "new address"
doc.Save("myfile.xml")
```

For more information read the following:

1. LINQ to XML is the technique I used here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx
2. XML serialization is another technique - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx

Comment: I have an error. NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instace of an object. Why?

Comment: The thing is that I have something like this <r1><root><address>myaddr</address></root>. And then <r2>...and the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's totally possible - and quite easily, too.

Read those resources:

- [Introduction to XML Document Object Model](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/XML/Introduction-to-XML-DOM/)
- [Introduction to Linq-to-XML: simple XML parsing](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing)

and a **great many more** - just search for "Intro Linq-to-XML" or "Intro XMLDocument" - you'll get **plenty** of links to good articles and blog posts.