# XML File changing contents

Tags: c#, xml

First off, the answer might be very simple, but I've tried many many normal seeming solutions and haven't got them working no matter what I tried.

I got this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Config>
      <PopulationSize>100</PopulationSize>
      <SpecieCount>20</SpecieCount>
      <Activation>
        <Scheme>FixedIters</Scheme>
        <Iters>1</Iters>
      </Activation>
      <ComplexityRegulationStrategy>Absolute</ComplexityRegulationStrategy>
      <ComplexityThreshold>500</ComplexityThreshold>
      <Description>
        Helikopter game
      </Description>
      <Timesteps>50000</Timesteps> //Length of the world (x-axis)
      <Worldheight>200</Worldheight> //Height of the world (y-axis)
      <SensorInputs>10</SensorInputs> //Length of one side of the rectangle that is used as the input. So 15 here means 15*15 = 225 inputs
      <Speler>computer</Speler>
    </Config>
```

And I want to edit the

```
    <Speler>computer</Speler>
```

to something like

```
    <Speler>mens</Speler>
```

Currently, I want something along the lines off:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Helikopter.config.xml");
        //Change the contents of "Speler" to "Mens"
        doc.Save("Helikopter.config.xml");
```

But I just can't seem to get it working, no matter what I try to put there, I've tried a lot of options on here already.

Help is appriciated, thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088312/how-can-i-read-and-edit-an-xml-file-using-c) it might be of some help!

Comment: XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("example.xml");                      xml.SelectSingleNode("//Speler").InnerText = "mens";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Helikopter.config.xml");

XmlNode node;
node = doc.DocumentElement;

// Iterate through all nodes
foreach(XmlNode node1 in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    // if the node is speler
    if(node1.Name == "speler")
    {
        // Change inner text to mens
        node1.InnerText = "mens";
    }
}

doc.Save("Helikopter.config.xml");
```

Comment: It seems to work, it doesn't give me errors, I put 'doc.ChildNodes' instead of 'node.ChildNodes' as I guess that is the intention. However, when I open the file after this has taken place, nothing has changed, so where does that issue come from?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my fault. I don't know why it isn't changing though

Comment: Could it be possible that the file is not closed properly after you saved it ? Try the same code but instead of using Save(string) use a StreamWriter to save the changes.

Comment: `doc.ChildNodes` gives the top level nodes in the document, which are the xml declaration and the Config element, it is not all the elements in the document. You'd either need to recurse when using that property, or use the xpath methods of xml document (`SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode`) to get the element you want. Also, it's case sensitive so you should look for `Speler` not `speler`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The capital sensitive thing is something I noticed earlier, but with the SelectSingleNode("Config") and then config.Childnodes, it works! Thank you all for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Config>
  <PopulationSize>100</PopulationSize>
  <SpecieCount>20</SpecieCount>
  <Activation>
    <Scheme>FixedIters</Scheme>
    <Iters>1</Iters>
  </Activation>
  <ComplexityRegulationStrategy>Absolute</ComplexityRegulationStrategy>
  <ComplexityThreshold>500</ComplexityThreshold>
  <Description>
    Helikopter game
  </Description>
  <Timesteps>50000</Timesteps> //Length of the world (x-axis)
  <Worldheight>200</Worldheight> //Height of the world (y-axis)
  <SensorInputs>10</SensorInputs> //Length of one side of the rectangle that is used as the input. So 15 here means 15*15 = 225 inputs
  <Speler>computer</Speler>
</Config>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        List<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants("Config").ToList();

        foreach (XElement elem in elements)
        {
            elem.Element("Speler").Value = "mens";

            Console.WriteLine(elem.Element("Speler").Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here an example how you can do it. You need to have reference to using `System.Xml.Linq;`