# asp.net edit nested xml nodes

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have generate a xml document from a database which represents my menu structure. However I want to edit a specific element within each of the nodes dependent on the page that the menu is being viewed from.

XML output has a structure like this

```
    <menus>
  <menu>
    <menuid>1</menuid>
    <menutitle>Home</menutitle>
    <menudescription>Main Page</menudescription>
    <menuurl>~/Default.aspx</menuurl>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <menuid>2</menuid>
    <menutitle>Users</menutitle>
    <menudescription>User Manamgement</menudescription>
    <menuurl>~/usermgt/users.aspx</menuurl>
    <menu>
      <menuid>5</menuid>
      <menuparentid>2</menuparentid>
      <menutitle>New User</menutitle>
      <menudescription>Create new user</menudescription>
      <menuurl>~/usermgt/NewUser.aspx</menuurl>
      <menu>
        <menuid>9</menuid>
        <menuparentid>5</menuparentid>
        <menutitle>Sub menu level 2</menutitle>
        <menudescription>test</menudescription>
        <menuurl>http://www.google.co.uk/#</menuurl>
        <menu>
          <menuid>11</menuid>
          <menuparentid>9</menuparentid>
          <menutitle>Sub menu leve 3</menutitle>
          <menuurl>#</menuurl>
        </menu>
        <menu>
          <menuid>12</menuid>
          <menuparentid>9</menuparentid>
          <menutitle>Sub menu leve 3</menutitle>
          <menuurl>#</menuurl>
        </menu>
      </menu>
    </menu>
    <menu>
      <menuid>6</menuid>
      <menuparentid>2</menuparentid>
      <menutitle>View / Edit Users</menutitle>
      <menudescription>View and edit current users</menudescription>
      <menuurl>~/usermgt/users.aspx</menuurl>
    </menu>
    <menu>
      <menuid>10</menuid>
      <menuparentid>2</menuparentid>
      <menutitle>3rd item</menutitle>
      <menuurl>#</menuurl>
    </menu>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <menuid>3</menuid>
    <menutitle>Menu</menutitle>
    <menudescription>Menu Manamgement</menudescription>
    <menuurl>~/menumgt/menu.aspx</menuurl>
    <menu>
      <menuid>7</menuid>
      <menuparentid>3</menuparentid>
      <menutitle>New Item</menutitle>
      <menudescription>Add new menu item to list</menudescription>
      <menuurl>~/menumgt/new_menu_item.aspx</menuurl>
    </menu>
    <menu>
      <menuid>8</menuid>
      <menuparentid>3</menuparentid>
      <menutitle>Edit Item</menutitle>
      <menudescription>Edit existing menu item</menudescription>
      <menuurl>~/menumgt/edit_menu_item.aspx</menuurl>
    </menu>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <menuid>4</menuid>
    <menutitle>Pages</menutitle>
    <menudescription>Page Editors</menudescription>
    <menuurl>~/pagemgt/pages.aspx</menuurl>
  </menu>
</menus>
```

What I want to be able to do is edit the `<menuurl>` node contents of each of the `<menu>` nodes whilst keeping the original layout of the document as a hole.

Can anyone offer any advice as to the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you check any of the XML related classes? Eg XDocument or XmlDocument? XML processing is providec by .NET itself. ASP.NET is only the web framework and doesn't offer anything specific for XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and edit an XML file using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088312/how-can-i-read-and-edit-an-xml-file-using-c)